# When Talking to a sensor IoT device from Bluemix Node-RED, what is the reasoning for registering a device?

Tags: arduino, device, ibm-cloud, arduino-uno, node-red

I want to set up Node-RED in bluemix to talk (2 ways) to my Arduino Uno with a temperature sensor.  What is the reasoning for registering the Arduino device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a device is registered with IotF, it then has its own topic space and credentials.  Using those credentials it can connect to IoTF and publish events and receive commands.  Only that particular device and applications with API keys can publish the events or receive commands sent to it.